# How to concatenate these arrays of strings?

Tags: python, arrays

I want to be able to add these to arrays so I get:

Input:

```
x = np.array(['C1', 'C2', 'C3'])
y = np.array(['C4', 'C5', 'C6'])
```

Output:

```
z = ['C1C4','C2C5','C3C6']
```

I've tried adding them both together:

Input:

```
str1 = 'Hello'
str2 = 'World'
print(str1 + str2)
```

Output:

```
HelloWorld
```

But this doesn't work for arrays as putting:

```
z = x + y
```

This just appends it to the end of the array and so could use some help to solve this.

Thanks, it's now been solved using:

```
z = np.array([a+b for a, b in zip(x, y)])
```

It worked beautifully thanks @Redone R.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

This might be solved using list comprehension

```
 z = np.array([a+b for a, b in zip(x, y)])
```

An equivalent way but this time without list comprehension:

```
 for a, b in zip(x, y):
    z.append(a+b)
 z = np.array(z)
```

Explanation:

The code is iterating over both arrays at the same time, concatenating every pair of elements and writing them to the resulting array

Comment: @DebanjanB thanks for mentioning it. I added more explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(str): 
    str = str.replace("'","")
    str = str.replace(",","")
    str = str.replace(" ","")
return str

z = list(zip(x,y))
newlist =[foo(str(word)) for word in z ]
```